# How to get confidence intervals after extracting robust standard errors in R?

Tags: r

First, i run a regression model. Then, i extract robust standard errors. However, i am not sure how to extract the confidence interval afterwards, `coeftest()` seems to include only the standard errors. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Here is the reproducible data and code:

```
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(broom)

data(Cigar)   
model<- plm(price ~ sales + cpi, index=c("state", "year"), model = 'within', 
                data = Cigar)
#Extract the robust standard errors    
plot_coeftest = tidy(coeftest(model))
```

Comment: Just add the `conf.int = TRUE` parameter to the tidy function, i.e. `tidy(coeftest(model), conf.int = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried it as you have suggested, but it did not work

Comment: It does in the example above. If it doesn't in your rela-world example, please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is not working for me in the example above. I thought that the issue is that i am having some packages overriding the functions of each others. But even when i run the following code, it does not work: `broom::tidy(lmtest::coeftest(model), conf.int = TRUE)`. 

Am i missing something?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Which part of the code? What error message are you getting?

Comment: The code is working, but i am just not getting the confidence intervals. I get only the: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value.

Comment: hmm, then I'm lost. Did you try restarting R? DId you update teh packages to their latest versions?

Comment: Finally it worked, thanks and sorry for the bother (it was the update!)

Comment: @jad, please post the answer as an **answer**, not as an edit to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @deschen proposed, this is the solution:

```
plot_coeftest= broom::tidy(lmtest::coeftest(model), conf.int = TRUE)
```